# Stripe Webhook Events - Matching Customer IDs?

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm testing a subscription product and firing events locally using `stripe listen --forward-to ...`. I believe my endpoint is set up correctly since it can listen for and receive events.

Issue: the customer IDs in the events do not match.

For example, the id in `customer.created` is `cus_J6l***Yu0`

The id in `customer.subscription.created` is `cus_J6l***yVb`

Also, the subscription IDs in `customer.subscription.created` and `customer.subscription.updated` do not match. `sub_J6l***ikY` and `sub_J6l***ufT` respectively.

It's unclear to me how to associate these events with each other. In a production setting, I could have many different customers creating subscriptions at a time. My expectation is that there's a key to associate customers and the subscriptions they create (or subscriptions and a subscription update).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `Subscription` is owned exactly by one `Customer`, see https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-customer. However, a `Customer` can have one or more `Subscription` which probably explains why you see a difference in the subscription ids, i.e. the events are fired for different `Subscription` but for the same `Customer`.  To view the full list of `Subscriptions` for a given `Customer`, see https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object#customer_object-subscriptions (note this is an `expandable` field).

Comment: This answer is correct. One customer owns each subscription but a customer can have many subscriptions. The IDs will match, you just have more objects in flight than you expect.